# Linking domain via cloudflare to google cloud

Tags: dns, hosting, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloudflare

Oke so here is the situation:

I have bought a domain from a **registrar(hostnet)** and my **hosting is on Google Cloud.**

Now i want to link the domain i bought from hostnet **via cloudflare** to Google Cloud.

I changed the nameservers of the registrar to use cloudflares nameservers. And then on cloudflare i changed the A records to point to my Google Cloud external IP-address.

The site works fine but on Google Pagespeed insight i see a 'delay in server response' so i'm thinking im doing something wrong. Also i haven't done anything on Google Cloud so it seems more like a redirect(slow) rather than a correct implementation. **That would mean anyone could link any domain name to my ip address..** that seems off.

**What would be the correct way to connect my domain from hostnet to my google cloud via cloudflares cdn.**

Comment: Any updates on how to fix solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, i'm still using the same settings.